# I am new to this and need to know the video format so that I can post it on youtube

Tags: windows-7, windows

I need to know what file format my video is and am unsure where to look.

many thanks

Comment: As my answer, you could have googled this VERY easily.

Answer (score 3):

The question seemingly asks how to find the format of an existing video.

> Right-click > Properties - Look under "Type of File"

Compare this to the formats [here](https://support.google.com/youtube/troubleshooter/2888402?hl=en) to see if they are YouTube compatible.

> .MOV,
>   .MPEG4,
>   .MP4,
>   .AVI,
>   .WMV,
>   .MPEGPS,
>   .FLV,
>   3GPP,
>   WebM,
>   DNxHR,
>   ProRes,
>   CineForm, and
>   HEVC (h265)

The linked article also includes tips for converting to a supported format.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the extension of the file to start with. That will probably give you a good idea. If Youtube rejects your upload, you may need to check what codec was used for the file. You can use a number of free programs for that, for example GSpot.

However, the easiest is that you go to your video editing software where you created the video and look at the settings there. If you open the file in that program, you should be able to look at the file properties and see exactly what codec and settings you used.

You should never post any videos you haven't created yourself.